# How can I calculate the correlation coefficient (R-values) for this set of values? (Linear Regression)

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have already calculated the slope, intercept, Pearson's r, p value, and standard error for the values below.

x-values

```
[1.2934100756644895, 1.2148454109214604, 1.1452785890167783, 1.0832475762335483, 1.0275908133381289, 0.977373796608513, 0.9318361831989935]
```

y-values

```
[-9.776387800749989, -9.175342621188113, -8.93878723996764, -8.422091376497663, -8.027043257822346, -7.681859756453859, -7.308696476846782]
```

Code:

```
slope1, intercept1, r1, p1, std_err1 = stats.linregress(C_to_K, ln_conversion_rate_CH4)

def myfunc1(C_to_K):
    return slope1*C_to_K + intercept1

mymodel1 = list(map(myfunc1, C_to_K))
plt.plot(C_to_K, mymodel1, "k:", label="y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}".format(slope1,intercept1))
```

Comment: Please, while asking the question also present your code here for us to examine what has actually gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you did:

```
from scipy import stats

x = [1.2934100756644895, 1.2148454109214604, 1.1452785890167783, 1.0832475762335483, 
     1.0275908133381289, 0.977373796608513, 0.9318361831989935]

y = [-9.776387800749989, -9.175342621188113, -8.93878723996764, -8.422091376497663, 
     -8.027043257822346, -7.681859756453859, -7.308696476846782]

slope, intercept, r, p, se = linregress(x, y)
```

In the [help page for lingress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), it already states:

```
r value float: Correlation coefficient.
```

So r is the correlation coefficient or Pearson's r as you stated in the question. If you need the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), it is basically square of r, which is

```
r**2
0.9927964085754613
```